# Is working Universal Windows Platform (UWP) on Linux,Mac,... based on dotNET Core?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know can I use UWP with dotNET Core 1.0 final release for creating application for Mac, Linux and etc or not ?

If no, is there any way for creating application based on dotNET Core 1.0 on other OSes or not ? something like JavaFX in Java or a cross platform of WPF ?

Please guide me how we can create multi platform application with dotNET core 1.0

Comment: Currently there are no MS-supported multiplatform (that include *nix OSes) tools for UI development.

Comment: Neither OSX nor Linux are Windows Platforms. So no, it won't work.

Comment: Do they plan for the future? Can we hope? Do you know ?

Comment: There is Xamarin , and several JavaScript solutions. None of them are 'UWP' though.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot.
UWP uses WinRT that is part of the windows. They haven't implemented the UI. Try Qt for example. That is cross platform.

For example in .Net Core you can create webapps with ASP.Net.

As far as I know Microsoft does not have a plan for implementing the UI of UWP for Linux now (2017.04.07).

Comment: @SmartManoj It has noting to do with the question. Dotnet Core runs on Linux devices, but UWP integrates with WinRT.

Comment: It is an answer to this same question.

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness:

[This page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/porting.md#prioritization) says that they work (or plan to work) on UWP for .NET Core on Linux and macOS.

There are already XAML and UWP (old name - UAP) related commits in [dotnet/corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) github repository, although i can only see the uap-Windows_NT build configuration in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher/tests/Configurations.props) file.

Comment: Microsoft is Slowly turning those softwares into opensource. Update your answer with this: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/12/04/announcing-open-source-of-wpf-windows-forms-and-winui-at-microsoft-connect-2018

Comment: This has nothing to do with UWP as dotnet core is cross platform, UWP is not. UWP is integrating with WinRT. You cannot run it on Linux machines.

Answer (score -1):

See this page
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/index

The following characteristics best define .NET Core:

**Flexible deployment**: Can be included in your app or installed side-by-side user- or machine-wide.
***Cross-platform***: **Runs on Windows, macOS and Linux**; can be ported to other operating systems. The supported Operating Systems (OS), CPUs and application scenarios will grow over time, provided by Microsoft, other companies, and individuals.
...

Comment: This really refers to server side dev, not client side deployments like UWP. From that link: ".NET Core can be thought of as a cross-platform version of the .NET Framework, at the layer of the .NET Framework Base Class Libraries (BCL)"